# App engine website coming soon

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud

App engine only works in US central. I accessed the site there, but when moved to the west coast, my website displays a "coming soon" page instead of the website I uploaded.

Answer (score -2):

URL link being entered was incorrect. I used the entire correct URL from app engine and it worked!